# Is a signature scheme using a hash considered a hybrid cryptosystem?

Tags: terminology, hybrid-encryption

In Wikipedia there is [a page on hybrid cryptosystems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem). However, although cryptography contains a lot more than just encryption, only hybrid encryption using key encapsulation and data encapsulation is discussed.

So my simple question is: should I consider a signature scheme using a hash a hybrid cryptosystem? Or is the term not *that* well defined and is it up to the entity that uses the term?

Comment: Isn't the word cryptosystem  only used for encryption?

Comment: Hmm, it is according to Wikipedia. Must be something from the olden days maybe. I was thinking that it is just several algorithm tossed together to create any kind of system. Could be the answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I didn't directly see is that a hybrid cryptosystem is not the same thing as hybrid cryptography. A cryptosystem is [**commonly** targeting encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptosystem): it exists of a key generation function $\operatorname{Gen}$, an encryption function $\operatorname{Enc}$ of course a decryption function $\operatorname{Dec}$.

So although signature generation could probably be called hybrid cryptography, it commonly isn't a hybrid cryptosystem because it lacks the $\operatorname{Enc}$ and $\operatorname{Dec}$ function.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to be careful when using these terms though, some clarification is probably in order.